# mod rewrite how do i add multiple rules with different combinations

Tags: mod-rewrite

i have been pulling my hair out for 3 days. i ve checked forums and tutorials but i just dont get it. i have a url of

```
    http://localhost/gallery/2012/2
```

but i also need to get

```
     http://localhost/gallery/2
```

this is my htaccess file

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9-]+)/([0-9-]+)/?$     index.php?page=$1&date=$2&pagenum=$3  [L]
     RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9-]+)/?$    index.php?page=$1&date=$2 [L]
     RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$    index.php?page=$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```

how would i go about adding another rule

```
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9-]+)/?$  index.php?page=$1&pagenum=$2 [L]
```